# convergence in probability and convergene in real valued squence

Tags: probability

Let $X_n, X$ be random variable on probability space such that $ X_n $ is convergence in probability to X

Let $ a_n $ be real valued sequence such that $lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = a$

then is it true that  $ a_n X_n $ is convergence in probability to aX?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Given any subsequence $(n_k)$ We can find a further subsequence ${n_{k_j}}$ such that $X_{n_{k_j}} \to X$ almost surely and $a_{n_{k_j}} \to a$. Hence $a_{n_{k_j}}X_{n_{k_j}} \to aX$ almost surely. This implies $a_{n_{k_j}}X_{n_{k_j}} \to aX$ in probability. Since every subsequence of $(a_nX_n)$ has a further subsequence converging in probability to $aX$ it follows that $a_nX_n \to aX$ in probability.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If $a_n\to a$, then $a_n\xrightarrow{p} a$. And you can use the properties of convergence in probability: limit in probability of product of convergent in probability two sequences equals to a product of their limits. 
Since  $a_n\xrightarrow{p} a$ and $X_n\xrightarrow{p} X$ then $a_nX_n\xrightarrow{p} aX$.